# gradle multi project build query - exclude compile based on env

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I'm using `gradle-7.2` with multi-project build feature, where my main service consists of multiple sub modules where i've defined structure like this:

```
MYSERVICE
----abc-api
    |
    ---build.gradle 
----abc-impl
    |
    ---build.gradle 
----xyz-api
    |
    ---build.gradle 
----xys-impl
    |
    ---build.gradle
lib
 <<all libs used by service extracted from subprojects compile/runtime classpath and placed here>>
bin
<<service startups scripts reside here>>
conf
<<service configuration files reside here>>
```

settings.gradle
build.gradle

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'MYSERVICE'
include 'abc-api'
include 'xyz-api'
include 'abc-impl'
include 'xyz-impl'
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

subprojects {
    task allDeps(type: DependencyReportTask) {}
}

configurations {
    runtimeClasspath.transitive = false
}

dependencies {
        
        /**
        * some additional runtime libs used by those subprojects
        */
        
        /** deps needed for spring framework **/
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:aopalliance:1.0"
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:spring-aop:5.3.22"
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:spring-tx:5.3.22"
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:spring-expression:5.3.22"
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:osgi.core:8.0.0"
        
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:disruptor:3.4.4"
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:commons-beanutils:1.9.4"
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:commons-io:2.11.0"
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:commons-logging:1.2"
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:guava:31.1-jre"
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.2"
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:objenesis:3.3"
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3"
        runtimeOnly "com.partygaming.thirdparty:jaxb-impl:2.3.6"

}

task getFlatDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from {
        subprojects.findAll { it.getSubprojects().isEmpty() }
                    .collect { it.configurations.runtimeClasspath + it.configurations.compileClasspath }
                    
    }
    into 'lib'
    
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    into 'lib'
    
    exclude "sourceanalyzer-1.0.jar"
}

build.dependsOn(getFlatDependencies)
```

All this works fine, but i want to do one additional improvement here. When i run `gradle build` at service level, its compiling all the sub projects and preparing lib.
I want to avoid this compilation stuff in case of QA environment (i download jars from artifactory for QA env) but needed for local environment setup.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: so , you do want to build only one at a time? or you want others to be compiled but without creating lib ?

Comment: No .. i dont want compilation at all in QA environments. For example, in abc-impl's build.gradle i'm already specifing abc-api as jar dependency like other thirdpary libraries. So i dont want to compile abc-api module in QA environments. So for service builds, i dont want the subprojects to be compiled again, instead just fetch from artifactory and prepare service's lib folder.

Comment: just to be clear, you want to escape compilation of other sub projects when building a solo project ? you want to build it as solo component.

Comment: yes.. you can think like that .. but i want to escape based on environment..